# How can you tell in FireBug what JavaScript is being sent back from the server after an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firebug

In my HTML I'm sending a dollar amount back to the server to have its currency changed in the app.

How can I tell in FireBug what JavaScript is being sent back from the server after this Ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the "Net" tab.

Answer (score 1):

Open the console tab and observe.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console tab > click the arrow button > select show XMLHttpRequests > run your script and observe in the CONSOLE or NET tab